# Will using functions to render content hurt react performance?

Tags: reactjs

This article (and other places) mention now calling functions inside of render:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/optimize-react-performance-c1a491ed9c36?ref=reddit

I've always used a pattern for large React class components where I'll move some of the JSX out of the render function into methods. This avoids having a billion little one-time-use separate components and it also avoids having to put lengthy if/then or ternary logic inside of a render area which I find *slightly* harder to read.

```js
class HelpModal extends React.Component {
  state = { visible: false };

  renderContent = () => {
    if (this) {
      return <div />
    } 
    if (that) {
      return <span />
    }
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <Modal visible={this.state.visible}>
         {this.renderContent()}
      </Modal>
    );

  }
}
```

I've seen this strategy in a bunch of places, but now it sounds like, based on the above blog post, that this may be a bad practice performance-wise?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you use inline functions.

React calls the render function after props and/or state changes. Each time they change the render function is called.

If you compute things that haven't changed because of the new props/state values then this inline function has indeed a negative impact on your app's performance.

Example:

```
render() {
    <div>
        { this.props.items.map(() => <SomeComponent />) }
    </div>
}
```

If you compute it here or anywhere else doesn't change the fact that you need to compute it each time the render function is called. No negative effect at all.

```
computeStaticStuff(x, y) {
    return x + y > 0 ? <p /> : <i />;
}

render() {
    <div>
        { () => this.computeStaticStuff(5, 6) }
    </div>
}
```

This would be a ((n) extremely stupid) example of recomputation that is not needed at all.