# Best way to use setInterval inside React useEffect in countdown timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

newbie to Javascript & React, trying to learn my way through React by building small projects. I'm working on a countdown timer right now, and I'm wondering if there's a better way of handling the pause/stop logic.

Right now, I'm calling `setInterval()` when my component is no longer in a "Paused" `!paused` state, and returning a `cleanup()` function to clear the interval. When I console logged it, it only cleared interval on pause/start.

However, I want to add functionality to automatically stop the timer once it hits zero, which requires adding `duration` state as a second dependency. When I logged this to console, I realized that my `setDuration` and `clearInterval` was now running at every interval, rather than only on the pause/start (it looks like it's calling `setInterval()` at every "tick" now.

My question is - is this a problem? And is there a better way to do this?

```
function Timer(props) {
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(10);
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timerId;
    if (!paused) {
      timerId = setInterval(() => {
        setDuration(prev => prev - 1);
      }, 1000);
      // console.log(timerId);
    }

    if (duration === 0) {
      // console.log(`Time's up`);
      clearInterval(timerId);
    }

    return function cleanup() {
      // console.log(`Clearing ${timerId}`);
      clearInterval(timerId);
    };
  }, [paused, duration]);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    !paused ? setPaused(true) : setPaused(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h3>{duration}</h3>
      <Button paused={paused} onClick={handleClick} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can simply clear the interval from *within* the interval if duration hits 0.

Comment: You may find the logic simpler and more maintainable to have a `useEffect()` which does nothing but cause a re-render at an interval. And then let your render function `Timer()` update the value of `duration` based on elapsed time. In-depth explanation and code samples at https://medium.com/@ErikH2000/react-animations-that-change-behavior-when-props-change-da026cec7548

Comment: Every time `duration` updates while not paused you are clearing the interval and starting a new one. So you would be better of using `setTimeout`. Or split your logic in multiple `useEffect` so duration doesn't impact the interval.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `duration` is changing on every interval and because it is passed as a parameter in dependecy array, it is triggering `useEffect` on each interval which is causing it to the `setDuration` and `clearInterval` to run at each interval.

you can use ternary operator to check if the duration is less than zero then you can automatically set the duration to zero by using `setDuration(0)`

```
function Timer(props) {
      const [duration, setDuration] = useState(10);
      const [paused, setPaused] = useState(true);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        let timerId;
        if (!paused) {
          timerId = setInterval(() => {
            setDuration((prev) => prev - 1);
          }, 1000);
          console.log(timerId);
        }
    
        return function cleanup() {
          console.log(`Clearing ${timerId}`);
          clearInterval(timerId);
        };
      }, [paused]);
    
      const handleClick = (e) => {
        !paused ? setPaused(true) : setPaused(false);
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          {duration >= 0 ? <h3>{duration}</h3> : setDuration(0)}
          <button paused={paused} onClick={handleClick} />
        </>
      );
    }
```

Play around with the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-yonath-so5d2t)

Comment: This is really interesting, thank you! I hadn't thought to do it this way. Are there any disadvantages to running `setDuration()` / functions generally in the render? I recall reading somewhere that this could cause performance issues, but I can't remember where.

Comment: @KokkoTso, It depends please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/47831991/13062632